# What is the "Merge" Button in GraphiQL?

Tags: graphql, graphiql

What is the purpose of the `Merge` button in GraphiQL UI. It seems to be doing the same thing as the `Prettify` button.

Please provide an example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Merge` button is used for flattening a query with defined fragments.
It is different from Prettify which retains the original query but just indents it.

Using the GraphiQL netify demo schema, the following query is "Prettified"

```
query {
  test {
    person {
      name
      age
      ...friendNames
    }
  }
}

fragment friendNames on Person {
  friends {
    name
  }
}
```

When clicking the `Merge` button the result is as follows:

```
{
  test {
    person {
      name
      age
      friends {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To see a live demo of the above, you can follow this [link](https://graphiql-test.netlify.app/?query=%23%20Click%20the%20merge%20button%20%20%20%20%20%5E%5E%0Aquery%20%7B%0A%20%20test%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20person%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20age%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20...friendNames%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afragment%20friendNames%20on%20Person%20%7B%0A%20%20friends%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

Comment: Thank you very much! Very clear and understandable answer.